# Subscriptions privileges / sub-priveledges

Tags: azure, admin

I'm very new to Azure (but very familiar with AWS). 
Our organization has a subscription that is used on a single tier level (e.g., there is one level of admin users that control all of the assets of the subscription).

My question is this: Given a single subscription, can users or groups of users be defined that have admin privileges over their own departmental or group assets?

Side note: I set up a trial subscription with Azure. That afternoon, I received a call from Microsoft Azure support and was told they were standing by to give support on user questions. So far all I get is voicemail from attempts to contact them.  (Gone are the days of actually getting support from Microsoft).

Comment: Here is a good article: http://blog.kloud.com.au/2013/07/30/good-practices-for-managing-windows-azure-subscriptions/.  ALSO: I've had very good experiences with MS support recently.  Make sure you give them a cell# to contact you; feel free to call back if you start playing "phone tag".  But you *should* get a response - and a satisfactory resolution.

Comment: Thank you for the link:  If I am interpreting that article correctly, the answer to my question is "yes, you can set up "sub-domains" e.g., sub-groups that have full admin over that subscription that is really a subset of a global company wide subscription.

Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, I believe so.  Alternatively, I believe you can also use ActiveDirectory if that better matches your requirements: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/active-directory/.

Answer (score 1):

The answer actually depends on the approach you use to deploy Azure resources.

When using the old approach (Azure Service Management API or https://manage.windowsazure.com portal), you don't have much granularity - you can only add other users as co-administrators which means that they have full access to all resources within the Azure subscription.

The new [Azure Resource Manager](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-overview/) approach (the API behind the new https://portal.azure.com portal), supports [role-based access control](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-rbac/) and allows you to manage access to individual resources and resource groups within the subscription.